# Not getting the correct position from viewpager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, viewpagerindicator

I am using viewpager in order to load images from the server, each fragment should load the image based on positon of the fragment in the adapter. so for example position 0 will load image 0 position 1 load image 1 etc. for the last two days I am struggeling with getting the correct fragment position, in total I have 3 fragments however from print outs I have added to the code I can see only position 0 and 2 and thus the image is duplicated in position 1.

the main question is how can I resolve this? I would like to get the correct position and based on that the correct image. below is the viewpager code and adapter code, it was modified several times based on several solutions however none of them seems to work

```
public class LoadCarFullSizeImage extends AppCompatActivity{

private ViewPager viewPager;
protected String imagePath;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.car_images);

    imagePath=getIntent().getStringExtra("imagePath");

    viewPager=(ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.vp_carViewPager);

    CirclePageIndicator titleIndicator = (CirclePageIndicator)findViewById(R.id.titles);


    PagerAdapter  mPagerAdapter = new ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(),imagePath);
    viewPager.setAdapter(mPagerAdapter);

    titleIndicator.setViewPager(viewPager);


}




@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (viewPager.getCurrentItem() == 0) {
        // If the user is currently looking at the first step, allow the system to handle the
        // Back button. This calls finish() on this activity and pops the back stack.
        super.onBackPressed();
    } else {
        // Otherwise, select the previous step.
        viewPager.setCurrentItem(viewPager.getCurrentItem() - 1);
    }
}



private static class ScreenSlidePagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter{

    private String imgPath;

    public ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fm, String _imagePath) {
        super(fm);
        this.imgPath=_imagePath;
    }


    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0: // Fragment # 0 - This will show FirstFragment
                return CarImageFragment.newInstance(0, imgPath);
            case 1: // Fragment # 0 - This will show FirstFragment different title
                return CarImageFragment.newInstance(1, imgPath);
            case 2: // Fragment # 1 - This will show SecondFragment
                return CarImageFragment.newInstance(2, imgPath);
            default:
                return null;
        }

    }


    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 3;
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using the indicator.. you have to getthe current page from it... and set current page using it too...
When using indicator stop using the pager or pager listener... any listener should be set to the indicator.

```
titleIndicator.getCurrentItem()==0...
```

and

```
titleIndicator.setCurrent.....
```